# AWS API Gateway call Lambda versions by header information

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, versioning

I've read a lots of API versioning hints for integrating AWS API Gateway with Lambda functions. But most of them used the URL to provide the version number e.g. `/v1/orders`

But I do not want to use this pattern. Instead I'd like to evaluate the header information to retrieve the requested version.

What I want to do is the following:

- configure API Gateway (via CloudFormation) in order to define only `/orders`
- use request mapping to read a header 'version'
- call a lambda function e.g. `getOrders:v1` if 'version' header is set to 'v1'

Is this possible with AWS Api Gateway? Or is there a similar approach that doesn't use URL to distinguish between versions?

I saw a solution by using stage variables:
https://dzone.com/articles/api-versioning-approach-with-aws-api-gateway

Regarding this approach: Is there an equivalent to `${stageVariables.v1fn}` for headers? E.g. `${request.headers.version}`?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use a lambda which dispatches the request to the lambda in question, API Gateway unfortunately only supports one lambda per endpoint and method

Comment: I edited my entry because it's possible to use ${stageVariables...} as Lambda Function name. In fact I need the same but for HTTP headers instead of staging variables :-)

Comment: I need to do the same, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Johnny90 have you found any solution on this?